# How to use variadic macros to call nested constructors?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to create a macro in Rust that lets me write

```
make_list!(1, 2, 3)
```

instead of

```
Node::new(1, Node::new(2, Node::new(3, None)))
```

which should work for an arbitrary number of "parameters" including zero. This is what I have so far:

```
macro_rules! make_list(
    () => (
        None
    );
        ( $x:expr, $( $more:expr ),* ) => (
        Node::new($x, make_list!( $( $more ),* ))
    )
);
```

but I get the following error:

```
error: unexpected end of macro invocation
  --> src/main.rs:19:42
   |
19 |             Node::new($x, make_list!( $( $more ),* ))
   |                                          ^^^^^
```

I can't make much sense of this. From what I can tell, it should work. What did I do wrong?

The complete code:

```
type List<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    tail: List<T>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(val: T, tai: List<T>) -> List<T> {
        Some(Box::new(Node::<T> {
            value: val,
            tail: tai,
        }))
    }
}

macro_rules! make_list(
    () => (
        None
    );
    ( $x:expr, $( $more:expr ),* ) => (
        Node::new($x, make_list!( $( $more ),* ))
    )
);

fn main() {
    let _list: List<i32> = make_list!(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
}
```

Comment: Your macro takes 0 or 2 arguments but you are only passing it 1

Comment: @Arjan: But I thought that's what the $(...),* is for. It should match zero to more arguments. Should it not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Expanding on the error: you get down to the case where there is only one value, and so it writes `make_list!(1)`. However, there is no rule that will match that, for the second rule, after consuming the expression `x`, wants a comma, which is not provided.

So you need to make it so that it will work for `make_list!(1)` and not just (in fact, just *not*) `make_list!(1,)`. To achieve this, get the comma inside the repeating part, like this:

```
macro_rules! make_list(
    () => (
        None
    );
    ( $x:expr $( , $more:expr )* ) => (
        Node::new($x, make_list!( $( $more ),* ))
    )
);
```

Bonus: you can write `make_list![1, 2, 3]` instead of `make_list!(1, 2, 3)` if you want.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm just too used to the magic of C++ variadic templates. :)

Comment: This approach no longer works; see [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/tail-recursive-macros/905/3).

Comment: Seems it [works again](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=macro_rules!%20make_list%28%0A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%0A%20%28%29%0A%20%29%3B%0A%20%28%20%24x%3Aexpr%20%24%28%20%2C%20%24more%3Aexpr%20%29*%20%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%0A%20%28%24x%2C%20make_list!%28%20%24%28%20%24more%20%29%2C*%20%29%29%0A%20%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20println!%28"%7B%3A%3F%7D"%2C%20make_list!%5B%5D%29%3B%0A%20println!%28"%7B%3A%3F%7D"%2C%20make_list!%5B1%5D%29%3B%0A%20println!%28"%7B%3A%3F%7D"%2C%20make_list!%5B1%2C%202%5D%29%3B%0A%20println!%28"%7B%3A%3F%7D"%2C%20make_list!%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%3B%0A%7D).

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @chris-morgan's answer, expanding the single argument case isn't accounted for.

So you can either include comma in the expansion, or add a single case in the macro:

Example of both, single argument:

```
macro_rules! make_list {
    () => (
        None
    );
    ($x:expr) => (
        Node::new($x, None)
    );
    ($x:expr, $($more:expr),+) => (
        Node::new($x, make_list!($($more),*))
    );
}
```

Including the comma in the expansion:

```
macro_rules! make_list {
    () => (
        None
    );
    ($x:expr $(, $more:expr)*) => (
        Node::new($x, make_list!($($more),*))
    );
}
```

Here is a fully working example based on the question and updated for Rust 1.14:

```
type List<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    tail: List<T>
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(val: T, tai: List<T>) -> List<T> {
        Some(Box::new(Node::<T> { value: val, tail: tai }))
    }
}

macro_rules! make_list {
    () => (
        None
    );
    ($x:expr $(, $more:expr)*) => (
        Node::new($x, make_list!($($more),*))
    );
}

fn main() {
    let list: List<i64> = make_list!();
    println!("{:?}", list);
    let list: List<i64> = make_list!(1);
    println!("{:?}", list);
    let list: List<i64> = make_list!(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    println!("{:?}", list);
}
```