# Possible to use a macro to expand into a tuple of constructors?

Tags: macros, rust

Given the following tuple assignment:

```
let (a, b, c, d) = (Item::new(1), Item::new(10), Item::new(100), Item::new(1000));
```

Can this be simplified so that the constructor could be removed and made into a macro. e.g.:

```
let (a, b, c, d) = item_tuple!(1, 10, 100, 1000);
```

From looking into recursive macros, it seems each macro instantiation needs to create a valid tuple, so the macro would create tuple pairs, e.g.: `let (a, (b, (c, d))) = ...;` ([see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41946667/432509)).

Is it possible to write a macro that expands into a flat-tuple of constructors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accept a variadic argument in your macro and expand it with a call to `Item::new()` around like so:

```
macro_rules! item_tuple {
    ($($arg:expr),*) => {
        (
            $(Item::new($arg),)*
        )
    }
}
```

With this macro this call will work and behave as expected:

```
let (a, b, c, d) = item_tuple!(1, 10, 100, 1000);
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f106d852af0a6e0564a3962b73b493e7&version=stable&backtrace=0)